# How to get my desired cryptocurrencies working in this JavaScript widget?

Tags: javascript, api, widget

I have a problem when trying to use a widget.

The script is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
baseUrl = "https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/";
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var embedder = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
(function (){
var appName = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
if(appName==""){appName="local";}
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
var theUrl = baseUrl+'serve/v3/coin/chart?fsym=TPAY*&tsyms=USD';
s.src = theUrl + ( theUrl.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "app=" + appName;
embedder.parentNode.appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
```

When I access `https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/serve/v3/coin/chart?fsym=TPAY*&tsyms=USD` from my browser it displays all the data but when using the widget script it does not seem to like the *fsym=TPAY*&tsym=USD but because cryptocompare lists some currencies that have the same ticker they add a * to the second currency which uses the same ticker name.

Another example of this is PHORE PHR* as they have PHREAK PHR already listed. Funny enough the currencies I would like to use it TPAY* and PHR*.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it does not seem to like it"? Do you get any specific error?

Comment: Basically any fsym that includes a currency without a asterisk works so if you were to use BTC in the script it works but ask soon as you use PHR* or TPAY* then it does not work. It seems to break this part - var theUrl = baseUrl+'serve/v3/coin/chart?fsym=TPAY*&tsyms=USD';

Comment: I would message their support team about this.

Comment: I have contacted their support team, the replay was (We are not retrieving any information for  Phore (PHR*)/USD this is why the chart is not working since there is no information to display.) but this is incorrect the data is flowing as you can see if you visit https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/serve/v3/coin/chart?fsym=TPAY*&tsyms=USD directly. The problem is the * asterisk used in the query string

Comment: Maybe try encoding the url string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: If the support team are saying "We are not retrieving any information for Phore", that sounds like it will not work until they start receiving that information?

Comment: (Please use titles to succinctly describe the problem you have. Please do not use them to beg and plead - that is not useful for your readers).